# Redis object serialization backwards compatibility

Tags: java, c#, serialization, backwards-compatibility

We serialized the following java entity and stored into **Redis**:

```
public class Foo {
    public String bar;
}
```

then our application **v2** modified the class Foo as:

```
public class Foo {
    public String bar;
    public Integer eggs;
    public Datetime happen;
}
```

Now when application v2 goes into production, in Redis, both Serialized **Foo V1** and serialized **Foo V2** are stored, and theirfore our application receives exceptions when deserialize objects from Redis. And now I've broken backwards compatibility.

It's not allowed to clean objects in Redis when our application upgrades from v1 to v2 because of business reasons.

Which approach is the best practice to avoid such backwards compatibility issue when design Redis data objects? Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an issue with Redis proper as I've done this from c#, but rather possibly an issue with your redis client.  What's the specific error you're getting?

Comment: Agree with @Fred, this is about how you serialized and version your injects as opposed to Redis. You will need to be more specific as to how you are serializing. Are you storing it as JSON, BSON, using msgpack, converting to a custom string representation, or some other way? Without those details the best you can hope for is a general "Search google for serializing java objects to a string" pointer.

Comment: @Fred, The Real Bill, you guys are right, actually it's a object mapping and serialization issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can fix it by configuring your JSON library

If you are using [Jackson library](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core) you have the option to ignore unknown properties by using

```
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

and if you are using the [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library you can use a cool feature that it has as version, by annotating your java classes with @Version annotation and it gives you the flexibility to have two different version of JSON co-existing together

Hope this helps

Comment: I solved the problem by myself. It's the client deserialization issue and I fixed it. Thank you.